# How to apply animation in CSS in my case?

Tags: html, angularjs, css, animation

I am trying to assign the class to do the animation based on a variable.

I have something like

```
//animationOn is default to false.
<div ng-click="animationOn = !animationOn">
  <div ng-class="(animationOn ? 'moveRight' : 'moveLeft')">
      contents..
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .moveRight{
        -webkit-animation: moveRightAni 1s;
        animation:moveRightAni 1s;   
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes moveRightAni{
        from {width: 100px;}
        to   {width: 300px;}
    }

    .moveLeft{
        -webkit-animation: moveLeftAni 1s;
        animation:moveLeftAni 1s;   
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes moveLeftAni{
        from {width: 300px;}
        to   {width: 100px;}
    }
```

My question is that when the page first loads, I always see the element scale from `300px` to `100px` animation shown because the `animationOn` is default to false. I need to have the element stay in `100px` when the page first loads instead of seeing it apply `moveLeftAni` animation. Is there anyways to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So there's three states - nothing (0), moveRight (1), and moveLeft (2). So make it default to nothing, and onclick make it something like `animationOn = animationOn == 2 ? 1 : 2`, the class something like `(animationOn ? (animationOn == 2 ? 'moveRight':`moveLeft`) : '')`.

You could also enable the CSS only after the first click by applying a class to the parent and using that in the CSS.